# MongoDB data storing ways: Which one is more efficient?

Tags: mongodb

Which way is efficient way to store MongoDB data? If we represent the data in tabular  structure it will look like this

```
id      name      title
1       ABC       XYZ
2       CDE       MNO
```

First way:

```
{
    1: {
        'name': 'ABC',
        'title': 'XYZ'
    },
    2: {
        'name': 'CDE',
        'title': 'MNO'
    }
}
```

Second way

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        'name': 'ABC',
        'title': 'XYZ'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        'name': 'CDE',
        'title': 'MNO'
    }
]
```

Also,

I want to query data on the basis of keys in the first way
and get value of 'name' only i.e. ABC. 
In second way this is easy but how to achieve it using first way.

I don't think I will be able to create index in the first way.
While I will have index on id in the second way.

Comment: I think second way is more efficient

Comment: Arrays have implicit keys… `doc[0].name`… If the `id: 1` doesn't have any explicit meaning in itself, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your ID has some implicit meaning like "1" is a home team and "2" is a visiting team in a sports scores - second option (arrays) is better. Easier to index and more flexibility for queries.

Also, remember the document size limit of 16Mb. If you have a really large number of embedded elements, that all together can reach this limit - you might need to normalize (create another collection and references).